# iCloud records only seen when directly searched

Tags: icloud

If I go to the iCloud dashboard and search (`Filter:`) for a record by exact `recordName`, the record is found.  However, if I search using any range or inexact methods (i.e. search by date range etc.), the record is not found.  Also, the record is not returned inside my Objective C program when I query all records of that type. It appears to be random records that have this characteristic. I recently inserted 40 or more records of this type (via software) and this behavior is only seen in 6 of them.  I have tried using the dashboard to update the affected records, in hopes that this might trigger "update" events on the backend.  Nothing that I have tried fixes this!!

I should add that my data is in the Development environment, not Production.

Answer (score 0):

I *may* have found a work around for this problem.  In the iCloud dashboard, I deleted the index `QUERYABLE` on the `recordName` field (the only index on this field) and then added it back. I then waited about 5 minutes or so and this seemed to fix the problem.  However, I believe that this is, perhaps, a bug in the backend iCloud server.